# Scriptrunner: Update Jira sub-tasks when version is updated

Tags: groovy, jira

I need to update Jira sub-task version field when parent task version is updated. And only when parent task version is updated.

I have been using existing script from Atlassian community forums https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Custom-update-listener-to-set-subtask-s-fix-version/qaq-p/591808 (written by Martin Hanus).

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.project.version.Version

IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(IssueManager.class)

Issue updatedIssue = event.getIssue()
Collection<Version> fixVersions = new ArrayList<Version>()
fixVersions = updatedIssue.getFixVersions()
Collection<Issue> subTasks = updatedIssue.getSubTaskObjects()
subTasks.each {
    if (it instanceof MutableIssue) {
        ((MutableIssue) it).setFixVersions(fixVersions)
        issueManager.updateIssue(event.getUser(), it, EventDispatchOption.ISSUE_UPDATED, false)
    }
}
```

This changes sub-task version correctly, but does it everytime parent task is updated. How can I get it to update only when parent task version is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to test the below code, so take it as a suggestion.

Source: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Marketplace-Apps-Integrations/Find-out-if-a-JIRA-update-event-changes-a-specific-issue-field/qaq-p/618091

You can check the old value of the field you are interested in, and abort your script if it was not udpated:

```
def change = event?.getChangeLog()?.getRelated("ChildChangeItem")?.find {it.field == "FixVersions"}
if (!change) {
    return
}
```